# jQuery UI strange button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to achieve something like this

[image]

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons

Getting

http://jsfiddle.net/p5PzU/1/

Why it's height so little? It's shape must be like square but I'm getting rectangle. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add some text inside the button element. Even a `&nbsp;` is fine. Then combine it with the `text:false` option. http://jsfiddle.net/p5PzU/2/